# Finding Cardinality of A Set After Complex Set Operation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A=\{ a_1,a_2,...,a_{n} \}$ and $B = \{ b_1,b_2,...,b_{n^2-3n+2} \}$ where $n \ge 2$ and all elements in $A$ are distinct, all elements in $B$ are distinct, and $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Now, let $d_i = \{ a_i \}$ for $i = 1,2,...,n$. In other words, $d_i$ is a singleton set containing the $i$th element in $A$.

Also, let $R_i = \{  d_i \cup p \}$ where $p \in \mathcal P(B) - \{ \emptyset \}$. In other words, each element of $R_i$ is the union between $d_i = \{ a_i \}$ and an element of the powerset of $B$, except for the empty set.

**What is the cardinality of the following set:**

$$ \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n} R_i$$

In other words, I am trying to derive a function $f : \{x \in \mathbb{Z} : x \ge 2 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f(n) = |\bigcup_{i = 1}^{n} R_i|$.

Any suggestions or answers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are all of the $a_i$ assumed to be distinct? What about the $b_i$? And are the $a_i$ and $b_j$ all pairwise distinct? Otherwise $A$ and $B$ could both consist of a single element even if $n$ is very large. For example: the set $\{3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3\}$ contains a single element. It doesn't matter that it is repeated in the list.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be well defined. "A distinct element" of the powerset cannot specify cardinality

Comment: good question. i will update the post. All elements in A are distinct, all elements in B are distinct, and all elements between the sets are distinct from one another as well.

Comment: @RyRy: for the definition of $R_i$ you meant to say $R_i=\{d_i \cup p\}_{p \in \mathscr{P}(B) \setminus \{\varnothing \}}$, perhaps?

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Yes that is a better way of stating it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power set of $B$ has $2^{n^2-3n+2}$ elements.

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then 
$$\left(\{a_i\}\cup p_1\right)\ne \left(\{a_j\}\cup p_2\right)$$
for any $i\ne j$ and any $p_1, p_2\in\mathcal{P}(B)$, because the two sets contain at least one different element. Therefore, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, all the $R_i$ are pairwise disjoint and contain $2^{n^2-3n+2}-1$ elements, so the cardinality of the union of the $R_i$'s is

$$\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^n R_i\right|=n\left(2^{n^2-3n+2}-1\right).$$

If $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint, then let $M$ be the number of elements they share (i.e., the number of $a_j$'s that are in $B$). Then, the set $R_j$ for each one of these $a_j$'s will just be $R_j=\mathcal{P}(B)-\{\}$. This is the same for all the $M$ $a_j$'s, but is disjoint with any of the $R_i$'s corresponding to the $a_i$'s that are not in $B$. Therefore, the cardinality when $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint is:

$$\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^n R_i\right|=(n-M+1)\left(2^{n^2-3n+2}-1\right).$$

Comment: haha! I actually derived this but for some reason didn't realize all $R_i$ are pairwise disjoint. Thanks!